# Parabola: Another Interesting Property

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let ABCD be a quadrilateral. Suppose there exists a parabola W<sub>A</sub> with focus A, tangent to lines BC, CD, and DB, and a parabola W<sub>C</sub> with focus C tangent to lines AB, BD, and AD.

Suppose that W<sub>A</sub>and W<sub>C</sub> are tangent to line BD at X and Y respectively. Prove that BX = DY.

[image]

I wish to solve the above problem using **coordinate geometry**

For the sake of simplicity we can assume either one parabola to be y² = 4ax, right? 
Could someone tell me how to proceed, and possibly post a detailed solution for the same?

I think proving BX = DY can possibly be done using pure geometry/congruence, but, as a student of analytic geometry I wish to proceed using the cartesian coordinate system.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is very nice property! Similar to incircle and excircle. I wonder if this is somehow valid also for ellipse and hyperbola.

Comment: Yeah, I know right! I wonder so too!

Comment: Is $ABCD$ cyclic? It seem that it is necessary for such configuration.

Comment: @John Watson: Yes, the quadrilater ABCD must to be cyclic: this can proved by applying Desargues involution theorem.

Comment: @Fabio Lucchini Actualy we don't need involution here, it is simple consequence of Simson's theorem. If we have three tangents with intersections A,B,C, then the focus of parabola is on circumcircle of triangle $ABC$.    https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ThreeParabolaTangents.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An analytic proof would necessarily involve parabolas whose axis is not parallel to a coordinate axis, so I think a more geometric approach is simpler.

Let $E$, $F$ be the tangency points of parabola $W_A$ and $G$, $H$ the tangency points of parabola $W_C$ (see diagram below).
It is a [well-known property of parabola tangents](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/ParabolaLambert.shtml) that
$\angle AEB=\angle ABX$ and $\angle ABE=\angle AXB$.
But $\angle ABE=\angle CBH=\angle CYB$ and $\angle CBY=\angle BAX$: it follows that triangles $ABX$ and $CBY$ are similar and
$$
BX:CY=AX:BY.
$$
By an analogous argument one can show that triangles $ADX$ and $CDY$ are similar and
$$
DX:CY=AX:DY.
$$
Combining the above proportions one gets
$$
BX\cdot BY=DX\cdot DY,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
BX\cdot (BD-DY)=(BD-BX)\cdot DY.
$$
From the last equality, it follows that $BX=DY$.

[image]

Comment: +1. The well-known property of parabola tangents is now weller-known! :)

Comment: BTW, the above shows, as an easy corollary, the result mentioned in the comments to the question: $\square ABCD$ is cyclic. (Performing the same angle analysis on the right-hand side of the diagram, one sees that the opposite angles of the quadrilateral must be supplementary.)